# Aria and Accessibility for the dynamic page title in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, accessibility, single-page-application, aria-live

Can any one guide me how to implement the accessibility on Single Page Application? My precise question is on announcing page title and new content.

**HTML**

```
<title data-ng-bind="TitleText" data-id="TitleAnnouncer" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></title>
```

Though page title is getting changed dynamically, screen reader is not recognising the change. I have used both cases for the attribute aria-live="polite" and "assertive" which is of no use.

Following are the links which I referred,

1. http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design/make-single-page-apps-work-screen-readers-101517155
2. http://simplyaccessible.com/article/spangular-accessibility/

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Were you able to find the answer to your question? I am having same issue.